# Entropy-based methods in R

Tags: r, modeling, maximum-entropy

I was wondering if anybody knows of the existence of an R package which implements entropy-based methods (maximum empirical likelihood, maximum exponential empirical likelihood, minimum discrepancy estimators, etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well there is a package which implements entropy-based methods and it is called .... entropy.

More information: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/entropy/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this personally, but a very good reference for R packages is the [R Graphical Manual](http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/r_image_list?page=942&init=true)

A search on that site of "empirical likelihood" gave several results, including EEF.profile from the boot package. There are also some packages that claim entropy methods (FNN), although I don't know precisely what you are looking for. I would check that site. Be as specific as you can with the search bar.